# Django one-to-many relationship on single model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to get django model with sections. Each section can have one or no super section and each section can have many sub-section. here is my model

```
class Section(models.Model):
    section_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sub_sections = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='super_section', null=True)
    links = models.ForeignKey('Link')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.section_name

class Link(models.Model):
    link_adress = models.URLField(max_length=2083)
    link_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    link_description = models.CharField

    def __str__(self):
        return self.link_text
```

The problem here is trying to get the admin panel working the way i want to. In the admin panel I want to be able to see and edit subsections and (here is my problem) want to be able to edit the super section my current section is under.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.StackedInline

Answer (score 0):

Your `ModelClass` `Section` is wrong. Right now a `Section` object can only have one sub section.
You should replace the `sub_sections` attribute with this:

```
super_section = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='sub_sections', null=True)
```

Doing it this way a `Section` object may have many sub-sections but has at most one super-section.

For more information about how `ForeignKey` works in Django have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).

**Now to the admin part:**

You can modify your admin panel to show related objects (i.e. super-sections and sub-sections) for a `Section` object as inlines (`TabularInline` or `StackedInline`). Please have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) for more information about the available `Inline` classes in Django.

**Code for an example inline:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from yourapp.models import Section

class SectionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Section

class SectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        SectionInline,
    ]
```

Comment: i tried doing the inline, but doesnt provide what im looking for. When adding a section i want to be able to put a name, select the parent section and add child sections if needed. I would prefer to be able to do this in a single admin page

Answer (score 0):

You've got your models wrong. If I understand right, this is what you want:

```
           Super-section
                |
             Section
          ______|______
         |      |      |
        Sub    Sub    Sub
```

This is how your models should look like:

```
class SuperSection(models.Model):
    # define your fields here
    # it doesn't need to have a ``ForeignKey``

class Section(...):
    super_section = models.ForeignKey(SuperSection)
    # define other fields
    # doesn't need any more ``ForeignKey``

class SubSection(...):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section) 
    # define other keys
```

Comment: this is not what im looking for as I would be limited to a total of 3 levels. I want to be able to have n levels if needed.